# Javascript - Change certain character color in input

Tags: javascript, dom

```js
var input = document.getElementById("wordTyped");
var word = document.getElementById("wordGenerated").innerHTML;

window.onload = function() {

  window.onkeydown = submit;

  function submit(evt) {
    if (evt.key == "Enter" && input.value == word) {
      input.value = "";
      input.style.color = "black";

    } else if (evt.key == "Enter" && input.value != word) {

      for (i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
        // Below is what I'm querying about
        if (input.value[i] != word[i]) {
          input.style.color = "red";
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="wordGenerated">illustration</div>
<input id="wordTyped" type="text" />
```

I don't think what I'm asking is even possible but I want to try changing the color of the `input` character that does not match with the `word`

For example,

wordGenerated: illustration

wordTyped: iilustration

The second 'i' in wordTyped should then change its color to red on `Enter`

I tried doing `input.value.style.color[i] = "red"` and `input.value[i].style.color = "red"`, but these in return give a TypeError color of undefined.

The code above changed the whole input text color into red.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is not possible. You'll need a (eg) `div` and make it [contenteditable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/contentEditable) to colorize each char.

Comment: Not possible. You should create your own component in order to do this. Best alternative is to use a third party component. It depends on what you are using as framework, library.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to wrap your letters in a span element.
NB: the code below is just a prof of concept, I didn't optimize it. 
I left optimization part to you.
good luck.

```js
var input = document.getElementById("wordTyped");
var word = document.getElementById("wordGenerated").innerHTML;

window.onload = function() {

  window.onkeydown = submit;

  function submit(evt) {
    var newWord=document.getElementById("wordGenerated");
        newWord.innerHTML="";
    if (evt.key == "Enter" && input.value == word) {
      input.value = "";
      input.style.color = "black";

    } else if (evt.key == "Enter" && input.value != word) {
      
      for (i = 0; i < input.value.length; i++) {
        // Below is what I'm querying about
        if (input.value[i] != word[i]) {
          var child = document.createElement( "span" );
          child.className='colored';
          child.innerHTML = input.value[i];
          newWord.appendChild( child );
        }
        else {
        var child = document.createElement( "span" );
            child.innerHTML = input.value[i];
            newWord.appendChild( child );
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.colored {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="wordGenerated">illustration</div>
<input id="wordTyped" type="text" />
```

Comment: Oh, this is neat, thanks! although, it's not what I have in mind, but I can use this method instead. I was aiming for the text in the `input` to change value instead. Is it possible though?